# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `defaultSource` supplied to `RCTImageView`

Tags: react-native

react - native, to set `<Image/>` component placeholder graphics failure, appear such a warning, could be set up in the wrong way, how to solve? thank you!

```
<Image defaultSource={'rn_new_default'} source={{uri:rowData.newspic}}
    style={styles.imageViewStyle}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `require` your image file.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#defaultsource

```
<Image
  defaultSource={require('./path/to/rn_new_default.png')}
  source={{uri:rowData.newspic}}
  style={styles.imageViewStyle}
/>
```

Comment: I tried the following two kinds of writing, but also doesn't work, why is this？

`defaultSource={{uri:'rn_new_default'}}`
`defaultSource={require('./rn_new_default.png')}`

Comment: which platform are you testing on, ios or android?

Comment: on ios platform,I think it is a bug of react-native.